# install dxpy with pip on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: python, 19.04, pip

I am trying to install a pip package called dxpy on Ubuntu 19.04. In the past, in ubuntu 16.04, I have done that using pip, but the following does not work on Ubuntu 19.04, see below. Any ideas?

```
albert_vilella_cegx_co_uk@avilella-ubuntu1904-bwamem2:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install -y python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate
albert_vilella_cegx_co_uk@avilella-ubuntu1904-bwamem2:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install -y python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
albert_vilella_cegx_co_uk@avilella-ubuntu1904-bwamem2:~/Downloads$ sudo pip install  dxpy 
sudo: pip: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

**use like**

abobe 18.04 all ubuntu

```
sudo pip3 install  dxpy
```

or

```
sudo  python3 -m pip install dxpy
```